# Ruby on Rails - Sqlite3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am new to both RoR and SQLite; So pardon my lack of knowledge.

I ran a scaffold command:

```
rails generate scaffold User password:string email:string
```

everything worked fine, next i ran the `rake db:migrate` command, the terminal suggested that everything was created.

Now i opened a new terminal and i wanted to verify that the table was created, so i hit `sqlite3` on terminal and ran `.tables` command, it shows null value.

So this time I ran `sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3` command and hit `.tables it` said unable to open database file

next I tried sqlite3 development.sqlite3 and hit `.tables` command and no results were shown.

I do not understand what I am doing wrong? and I am unable to find a decent tutorial which walks one through this. please help.

here is my .yml file:

```
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  <<: *default
  database: db/development.sqlite3


test:
  <<: *default
  database: db/test.sqlite3

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3"
```

Comment: `rails console` and than `User.all` and check if the users were created

Comment: Just literally replayed that. `rails new whatevs && cd whatevs`; `rails g scaffold User password:string email:string`; `rake db:migrate`; `sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3`; `.tables`: outputs `schema_migrations users`. All fine.

Comment: I want to check from SQLITE console...

Comment: A Rails way to enter database console is `rails db` by the way.

Comment: D-side when i run that I get "Error: unable to open database "db/development.sqlite3": unable to open database file"

Comment: It might have been corrupted, for whatever reason. Try deleting it, then running `rake db:create db:migrate`. Permissions may be wrong as well. If the database file originates from a different machine/OS, there is another scope of possible problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When done from-scratch, this sequence of actions produces expected results:

```
SQLite version 3.8.2 2013-12-06 14:53:30
Enter ".help" for instructions
Enter SQL statements terminated with a ";"
sqlite> .tables
schema_migrations  users
```

So problems are specific to your database. Most likely, the file was corrupted. There are many reasons why that could happen, and the easiest workaround (if data in that file is not important) is just to wipe the database file and recreate it:

```
rm db/development.sqlite3
rake db:create db:migrate
```